# Angular 8 Jasmine spy and returnValue with different type

Tags: angular, jasmine, openapi-generator

I have my REST service generated by openapi-generator-cli.
So the generated services looks like :

```
public list([...paramaters]): Observable<Array<CustomObject>>;
public list([...paramaters]): Observable<HttpResponse<Array<CustomObject>>>;
public list([...paramaters]): Observable<HttpEvent<Array<CustomObject>>>;
public list([...paramaters]): Observable<any> {
    [generated service code here]
}
```

My problem is when I want to test the service with :

```
const httpServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpCustomObjectService', [
    'list',
    'create',
  ]);

if('should', () => {
    const listOfValues: CustomObject[] = [value];
    httpService.list.and.returnValue(of(listOfValues));
})
```

I can't even build cause I always have :

```
Argument of type 'Observable<CustomObject[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<HttpEvent<CustomObject[]>>'
```

I can write :

```
httpService.list.and.returnValue(of(new HttpResponse({ body: listOfValues})));
```

but the rest of my code fails cause is not expecting Observable< HttpEvent< Array< CustomObject>>> but Observable< Array< CustomObject>>

Is there a way to choose the return type of 'returnValue' between all possible auto generated ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `as any` so that TypeScript understands that you take all the responsibility for type inconsistency.

Thus you need to update your code to this `httpService.list.and.returnValue(of(listOfValues) as any);`